# Uso de tokens temporales en diferentes sesiones (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, axios

Actualmente ando trabajando en un backend que gestiona una serie de llamadas a una api privada de una compañía ajena a mí. Dicha [api privada](https://docs.xandr.com/bundle/xandr-api/page/authentication-service.html) tiene un sistema de login que al llamar al "/auth" devuelve un token válido por 2h. La cuestión que me ha hecho preguntar esto es que, simplemente no encuentro forma de encapsular un método seguro al que yo pueda llamar para verificar que se ha iniciado sesión.

El código que he desarrollado para subsanar de alguna forma con este problema es el siguiente:

```
  apiAuthLogin() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get('/member')
      .then(async (res) => {
        resolve("Previously logged in.");
      }).catch(async (error) => {
        if (error) {
          await axios.post('/auth', {
            "auth": {
              "username": user,
              "password": password
            }
          }).then(async (res) => {
            this.readWriteAsync(res.data.response.token).then(() => {
              resolve(res.data.response.token);
            });
          })
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }
      })
    })
  }

  readWriteAsync(token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('./.env', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject();
          throw err;
        }
        let newValue = data.replace(/API_TOKEN=.*/, `API_TOKEN=${token}`);
        fs.writeFile('./.env', newValue, 'utf-8', function(err) {
          if (err) {
            reject();
            throw err;
          }
        });
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

Haciendo un breve resumen, hay un fichero .env que contiene el token que axios debe utilizar para las llamadas a dicha API, el mayor obstáculo que veo es que la escritura sobre el fichero .env que ejecuto en el método "readWriteAsync" no es del todo eficaz en una primera ejecución del programa tras las 2h de caducidad del token, dado que para cuando se ejecuta el programa, axios lee la variable de entorno inicializada con el token anterior, no con el actual. Existe alguna forma de resolver esto?

Disculpen de antemano por la extensión de esta pregunta, pero damos por hecho que seguro que todos hemos visto respuestas bíblicas.

Comment: Porque estas guardando el token en un archivo? y si quieren conectarse varias personas?

Comment: @gbianchi a esta API solo se puede conectar un usuario administrador, que es el que tiene los permisos dando por la empresa que comento, de ahí que lo guarde en un archivo, sinceramente no le di más vueltas. No sé si la solución pasa por levantar una base de datos de la que se extraiga el token al momento de hacer la consulta, pero esto añadiría latencia al proceso. De igual manera, buen apunte a tener en cuenta el multiusuario o multiacceso dada la naturaleza de este tipo de servicios

Comment: ok.. entonces tambien, con un archivo, supongo que tenes tu servicio en una sola pc, y no en una granja o en otra cosa? ;) igual, si la api no tiene un refresh token, entonces ponele la fecha y listo.. no termino de entender el problema...

Comment: ahhh y seguro que la latencia a la db es mucho mayor que la latencia al SO...???? ;)

Comment: @gbianchi sí, el caso es que el servicio está solo en mi equipo. La api refresca el token cada 2h y limita los inicios de sesión a un número concreto en un tiempo determinado, de ahí que no opte por la vía de hacer una llamada a "/auth" siempre y generar tokens por cada sesión

Comment: entonces guarda el tiempo y listo...

Comment: @gbianchi en el tema latencias, al tratarse de un fichero .env se carga en ejecución del servicio, es cierto que la escritura es lo que puede demorar todo el proceso ya dentro de dicha ejecución, es bastante valorable, no sé si has escuchado la práctica del rubber-duck pero es aplicable a este caso ;)

Comment: totalmente.. me estas usando de patito y me doy cuenta.. :p la latencia entre el archivo y la db, deberia ser despreciable.. los dos van a guardar a disco, pero la db a veces lo hace mejor en algunos casos... igual, vuelvo a preguntar.. y el problema es????

Comment: @gbianchi el problema pasa por no querer hardcodear tokens ni claves de accesos y mirando a futuro, este servicio va a ejecutarse 8h al día como parte de un backoffice, lo que me obliga a sellar todo este proceso para no generar errores constantes dado el sistema en la autenticación

Comment: Entonces yo particularmente no estoy entendiendo tu problema.. tal vez alguien mas te entienda...

Comment: Cuando haces un llamado al /auth que otros valores te llegan además del token? no te llega un refresh_token o algo parecido?

Comment: @Pipe por desgracia no. Se me olvidó enlazarlo https://docs.xandr.com/bundle/xandr-api/page/authentication-service.html el servicio es bastante concreto para realmente todo

Comment: Si tu aplicacion corre en multiples instancias, sugeriría almacenar el token en la base de datos (si es que usas una), sino, sugeriría por ejemplo usar redis para el almacenamiento del token ya que es algo sencillo y muy rapido... allí almacenarías el token y el momento en que lo generaste, si en una siguiente peticion detectas que ya pasó mas de una 1:45 mins (por ejemplo), generas un token antes de realizar la peticion al servidor. Si no usas bases de datos y si tu app no es multi instancia, de igual manera podrías tener una variable global dentro de node, para usarla con el mismo proposito.

Comment: @Pipe pues muchísimas gracias porque creo que junto a gbianchi has dado con la solución, no estaba haciendo uso de una base de datos hasta el momento, pero viendo la expansión del proyecto es verdad que podría ser útil a largo plazo, así que ahora lo tengo en mongdb (que además es súper sencillo desde Node) y todo funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias a los dos <3